# SQL How to find the AVG number of trips taken by 2 different groups for each day in a year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My dataset, `bike_trip_2019`, contains bike trip data from 2 different `user_type`: member and casual.

| trip_id | started_at | ended_at | user_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 07.30 UTC | 2019-01-01 07.40 UTC | member |
| 2 | 2019-01-01 09:20 UTC | 2019-01-01 09:46 UTC | member |
| 3 | 2019-01-02 14:20 UTC | 2019-01-02 14:45 UTC | casual |
| 4 | 2019-01-02 16:20 UTC | 2019-01-02 17:05 UTC | casual |
| ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... |
| 9999 | 2019-12-31 06:20 UTC | 2019-12-31 06:50 UTC | casual |

I want to find out the average number of trips taken by each user type for each `day_of_week`.
The expected result table looks kinda like this :

| day_of_week | avg_num_member_trips | avg_num_casual_trips |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sun |  |  |
| Mon |  |  |
| TUe |  |  |
| Wed |  |  |
| Thu |  |  |
| Fri |  |  |
| Sat |  |  |

What query should I use to achieve the same / similar result?

Answer (score 3):

Consider below approach

```
select day_of_week, 
  cast(avg_num_trips_member as int64) avg_num_trips_member,
  cast(avg_num_trips_casual as int64) avg_num_trips_casual
from (
  select user_type, count(*) trips,
    format_date('%a', date(started_at)) day_of_week,
    extract(dayofweek from date(started_at)) pos
  from your_table
  group by user_type, day_of_week, date(started_at), pos
)
pivot (avg(trips) avg_num_trips for user_type in ('member', 'casual'))
order by pos
```

with output like

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm, but can you clarify why the 'pos' column is needed? Isn't the 'day_of_week' column enough? @Mikhail

Comment: POS allows you to have weekdays in proper order

Comment: Thank you, one more thing Sir... You use 'cast' to change the data type into Int64. Why is that? What is it originally? @Mikhail

Comment: You can leave it float - but I prefer to see int for metrics which has nature of int. For example it would sound weird to me to have 21634.56 trips. I would rather expected to see 21634. Obviously this also depends on scale of metric - for example if metric would be in range of let’s say 2 and 4 keeping it as float would make sense, but still, in this case I would use round function

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to mock some data and write the query. You can use DATETIME functions to fetch the day based on `ended_at` column.

```sql
WITH dt as (SELECT ARRAY[
    STRUCT("Sun" as day , 'member' as memtype), 
    STRUCT("Sun" as day , 'member' as memtype), 
    STRUCT("Sun" as day , 'casual' as memtype), 
    STRUCT("Mon" as day, "casual" as memtype), 
    STRUCT("Mon" as day, "member" as memtype)
  ] as cols)
SELECT
col.day,
COUNTIF(col.memtype = 'member') as member_trip,
COUNTIF(col.memtype='casual') as casual_trip,
AVG(CASE WHEN col.memtype = 'member' THEN 1 else 0 END) as avg_mem_trip,
AVG(CASE WHEN col.memtype = 'casual' THEN 1 else 0 END) as avg_casual_trip
FROM dt, UNNEST(dt.cols) as col
group by day
```

Answer (score 0):

If each trip starts and ends on the same day, you can use this

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, started_at))) AS Trip_Date,  AVG(CASE WHEN user_type="member") AS Member_Trips,  AVG(CASE WHEN user_type="casual") AS Casual_Trips FROM bike_trip_2019 Group by DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, started_at))) order by DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, started_at)))
```