# SQL Solve conflicting results in finding AVG trip duration for each day in a year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this.
It contains bike trip data from 2 different `user_type`: member and casual.

| trip_id | started_at | ended_at | user_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 07.30 UTC | 2019-01-01 07.40 UTC | member |
| 2 | 2019-01-01 09:20 UTC | 2019-01-01 09:46 UTC | member |
| 3 | 2019-01-02 14:20 UTC | 2019-01-02 14:45 UTC | casual |
| ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... |
| 9999 | 2019-12-31 06:20 UTC | 2019-12-31 06:50 UTC | casual |

Inside the result table, I try to get both  average number of trips AND average trip duration taken by each user type each day.

```
WITH cleaned_data2 AS (
  SELECT 
    user_type, 
    COUNT(*) trips, 
    AVG(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE)) avg_trip_duration,
    FORMAT_DATE('%a',DATE(started_at)) day_of_week,
    EXTRACT (dayofweek FROM DATE(started_at)) pos
  FROM `capstone-361002.Cyclistic_bike_share.Merged-bike-trip-data`
  GROUP BY user_type, day_of_week, DATE(started_at), pos
  )

SELECT day_of_week,  
  CAST(avg_num_trips_member AS int64) avg_num_trips_member,
  CAST(avg_num_trips_casual AS int64) avg_num_trips_casual,
  avg_duration_member,
  avg_duration_casual
  
FROM cleaned_data2
PIVOT (AVG(trips) avg_num_trips, AVG(avg_trip_duration) avg_duration FOR user_type IN ('member', 'casual')) AS pv
ORDER BY pos
```

Format of result table :

| day_of_week | avg_num_trips_member | avg_num_trips_casual | avg_duration_member | avg_duration_casual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sun |  |  |  |  |
| Mon |  |  |  |  |
| TUe |  |  |  |  |
| Wed |  |  |  |  |
| Thu |  |  |  |  |
| Fri |  |  |  |  |
| Sat |  |  |  |  |

However,  I find that the value of AVG duration columns differ greatly when I instead wrote this query:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%a',DATE(started_at)) day_of_week,
  AVG(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE)) avg_trip_duration
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_type, day_of_week
```

Any idea why this happened? Which one is correct? And how should I revise the first query to get the correct average duration of trips taken each day in a year?

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why this happened? Which one is correct?

The first approach makes sense when you ask for average daily / per-week-day counts - as it is answered in your previosu question - [SQL How to find the AVG number of trips taken by 2 different groups for each day in a year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73564487/5221944)

But when you formally apply same approach to average duration - what you really do you do average twice - and that is why you get wrong numbers!

so you second query is correct for average duration!

Comment: have this helped?